# UIImageView で、ボタンを押すごとに画像を番号順に切り替えるには

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, iphone

iPhone アプリを作成中です。

タイトルのとおり、「ボタンを押すごとに画像をファイル名の番号順に切り替えていく」ことをしたいです。具体的には、

- 画像ファイル （ファイル名： photo01〜10 )を用意する
- `UIImageView`に画像が表示されるようにする（最初は photo01 )
- ボタンを押すと photo02 が表示される。
- もう一度ボタンを押すと photo03 が表示される

といった具合にしたいのですが、ソースはどのようなものになるのでしょうか？  
不勉強で申し訳ありませんが、どなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか。  
以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 単純にUIImageViewのimageを入れ替えればできるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、具体的にはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答に簡単なサンプルコードを添付しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageViewのimageを変更すると画像の変更が可能です。

連番画像の読み込みは現在表示している画像のIndexを保持して、読み込むときにformatすればできると思います。

サンプル作ってみました
https://github.com/seijiro/image-change

実装次第だと思いますが、だいたいこんなので良いでしょうか？

```
- (IBAction)prev:(id)sender {
    currentIndex -= 1;// 現在表示中の画像のIndex
    // UIImage取得
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self format:currentIndex]];
    // 切り替え
   _imageVIew.image = image;

}

- (NSString) format:(NSInteger)index{
    NSString *BASE_FILE_NAME = @"%2d.jpg";
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:BASE_FILE_NAME, index];
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました！助かりました！

Comment: 解決した場合は投票ボタンの下にあるチェックボックスを押していただければと思います。